# Why are Faker's methods in several modules?

Tags: ruby, faker

I'm looking at this Gem:
https://github.com/stympy/faker

I use it quite a lot, and it is very good, but I don't get why all of its methods are organised into modules:

```
Faker::Code.isbn #=> "759021701-8"
Faker::Address.longitude #=> "-156.65548382095133"
Faker::Bitcoin.address #=> "1HUoGjmgChmnxxYhz87YytV4gVjfPaExmh"
```

I have to do this in my factories:

```
factory :person, class: Person do
    name { Faker::Lorem.word }
    account { Faker::Bitcoin.address } 
    address { Faker::Address.longitude }
    favourite_book { Faker::Code.isbn }
end
```

Can I include all of the modules into my test suite so I just need to do this:

```
factory :person, class: Person do
    name { word }
    account { address } 
    address { longitude }
    favourite_book { isbn }
end
```

I'm using rspec:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
  # doesn't work: config.include Faker
end
```

Why have they bothered separating their methods into separate methods? To make it faster? Surely this is a negligible amount unless you've got an insanely complex project? Wouldn't a better gem just let you do `BetterFaker.word`, `BetterFaker.address` ect? Be easier to remember :)

Comment: Why don't you ask them why they wrote it that way? I don't think SO is the right place to ask about this.

Comment: Faker isn't meant to be included anyway, `Faker::Bitcoin.address` will collide with the method `address` of the factory.

Answer (score 0):

I am willing to venture that the authors of the gem like to organize their files in a logical manner, and keep methods that have different scopes in different places.